# Running django test, migrations with django.conf import settings are not using DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or --settings override settings

Tags: python, django, testing, settings

I have a migration which does a check on `settings.DEBUG`, I've imported settings using

```
from django.conf import settings
```

and if it's `False` I'm expecting that this is a production(or production-ish) environment so I'm importing a secrets manager secret to use in a createsuperuser migration function, otherwise it's local hosting or local dev and I'm just using a hard coded string.

My problem is that in my `settings.py` I've set `DEBUG` to false as a safe default, similar to how I set my `SECRET_KEY` to None so that if for some reason the settings override fails I get an error not the generated `SECRET_KEY`.

Anyway, back from that aside, I'm trying to run `./manage.py test --settings=myproject.test` (I have also tried using an export of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myproject.test'`) to load my `test.py` settings file, at the top of which it does a `from .settings import *` import and then further down the page I overwrite the setting with `DEBUG = True`.

So in my migration I `from django.conf import settings` and I'm expecting that to load my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` settings, when I run my tests and it runs my migrations, I'm expecting that `from django.conf import settings` is going to use my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` settings I used when I ran the tests, but it doesn't seem to do so.

What I tried, if I add a print statement in the settings overrides file directly below my setting override for DEBUG I can see that the setting is set correctly at the point that that print statement happens.  But if I also add a print statement within the block in my migration, I can see that the setting is not from the overrides file, as it's set to `False`.

If I try to apply `from django.test import override_settings` and `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` to the test class, it still doesn't read `DEBUG` as `True`, neither does applying it to the base class, I'm not using `self.settings` anywhere, and I'm still trying to find out what's going on.

I've realised that I've not said that I'm using `StaticLiveServerTestCase` as my class that I'm inheriting from in my testing base class.

Comment: A bit more Googling and reading the Django docs site and I now see that this seems to be expected behaviour https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions

Answer (score 0):

So, as noted in my comment to my post that this was expected behaviour, but I still needed a solution to run with `DEBUG = True` and this is possible by adding a command line argument of  `--debug-mode` to the `./manage.py test` command.